# ComboBox not updating DataBindings on selected item changed (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a ComboBox bound to a data source but it will not update the bindings until the control loses focus. How can I get the bindings to update when the selected items change? In the screen shot below I'd like the label to updated immediately to reflect the new selection.

[image]

Some Code:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
  First,
  Second
}

public class MyData
{
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public MyEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
}
```

Sample Form:

```
public SampleForm()
{
  InitializeComponent ();   
  MyData data = new MyData () { Name = "Single Item" };
  this.bindingSource1.DataSource = data;
  this.comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues (typeof (MyEnum));
  this.label2.DataBindings.Add ("Text", this.bindingSource1, "MyEnum", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
  this.comboBox1.DataBindings.Add (new System.Windows.Forms.Binding ("SelectedItem", this.bindingSource1, "MyEnum", true));
  this.comboBox1.DataBindings.Add (new System.Windows.Forms.Binding ("SelectedValue", this.bindingSource1, "MyEnum", true));
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Comment out the SelectedItem version, and modify the SelectedValue binding like this to include the UpdateMode:

```
this.comboBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding(
                                      "SelectedValue",
                                      this.bindingSource1,
                                      "MyEnum",
                                      true,
                                      DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

Comment: This worked for me too. Thanks. But it doesn't load the inital value of MyEnum. Do I have to do this manually?

Comment: @ehmunnehm I don't know what your code looks like to answer that.  Try posting a new question with the proper reproduction code.

Answer (score 5):

[LarsTech solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19553119/521326) is correct. You can also do it in design mode:

1. ComboBox Properties (F4) -> DataBindings node -> Advanced
   [image]

---

2. Click on 'SelectedValue' and change Data Source Update Mode to 'OnPropertyChanged'
   [image]