# Data-bound combobox not updating its datasource on SelectedItem

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a databound combobox. It's bound as follows:

```
cbo.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("SelectedItem", this.bindingSource, "Order", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, null));
```

And it's populated as follows:

```
cbo.DataSource = customer.Orders.Where(x => x.Month == month).ToList();
cbo.ValueMember = "OrderId";
cbo.DisplayMember = "OrderDate";
cbo.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

The data source is a `BindingSource` which is in turn bound to a DTO class.

If I select an item and move focus to another control using `TAB` the `SelectedItem` is set correctly.

However, if I select an item and click on another control the `SelectedItem` will be the previously selected item when tabbing out of the control.

I've tried a mixture of binding `SelectedItem`, `SelectedValue`, `OnPropertyChanged` and `OnValidation` but all result in the same problem if not tabbing out.

A part-solution was given in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552912/combobox-not-updating-databindings-on-selected-item-changed-winforms), however, in my case, it's not working.

The current workaround is to do:

```
(bindingSource.Current as Customer).Order = selectedOrder;
```

Which should be unnecessary because the datasource is bound. Is there a better way to enforce the change to be committed when clicking another control instead of tabbing out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ComboBox` does not provide `SelectedItemChanged` event which is required for correctly binding to `SelectedItem`.

You should bind to `SelectedValue` instead, which works correctly. The problem is that there is no way to specify using the `DisplayMember` as display and the data source object as `ValueMember`. One way to solve it is to use a specialized object (a.k.a. view model) for the list elements. For instance, using anonymous type projection:

```
cbo.DisplayMember = "OrderDate";
cbo.ValueMember = "Order";
cbo.DataSource = customer.Orders.Where(x => x.Month == month)
    .Select(o => new { o.OrderDate, Order = o })
    .ToList();

cbo.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("SelectedValue", bindingSource, "Order", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, null));
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically "OnPropertyChanged" will enforce the databinding to write value into underlying object when the control lost focus. but somehow it does not; so I guess somewhere the databinding was not done properly:

1. is the databinding bound to the correct object?
2. is the previous databinding cleared when the bound object is being changed?
3. did you try to change this.bindingSource to your object directly, instead of going through bindingSource wrapper?

normally if you wish to enforce data written back to object for databinding, you can call binding.WriteValue().

something like below:

```
    cbo.LostFocus += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
        foreach (Binding b in cbo.DataBindings)
        {
            if (string.Equals(b.PropertyName, "SelectedItem"))
            {
                b.WriteValue();
            }                    
        }
    };
```